# VMs auto start stop for multiple regions in multiple projects in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, virtual-machine, auto

I am trying to implement a solution for vm auto start/stop as per a through automation . I was able to do so using the below link :

https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule

But the problem here is that this is for vms running in a single region and also a single project .

Does anyone has any idea or has implemented a similar solution for vm auto start/stop but for multiple regions in a single project or multiple projects .

Any leads would be helpful !!

Note : The purpose for doing this is for cost optimisation across projects .

Thanks

Comment: Scheduling start and stop is built into the Compute Engine API. See if the document provides the features you require: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop